# Solr multiple cores for multiple document types and joining them. Performance?

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm planning to split up 1 schema to multiple schema's. This will allow me to run multiple cores with different document types. Then I will use join to get the related documents if needed.

At the moment I had multiple document types by using a type field.

**How will this change affect the performance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when you join between cores, you will be able to get information from only one core (not the other).

In my opinion, Solr works the best when it has to pull data from one location only. Joining might produce an overhead, thus essentially slowing the whole operation.

However, consider the following situation :- a user has 20 million records in one core and Solr has to search each and every record in that. If the user is able to separate them into two cores , one having 1 million records and the other core has 20 records, then joining might be efficient in such a case.

Summary :- it depends on how much data you have now, how much data you will have when you have multiple cores. If your situation is not like the above, then I suggest that you look for some other alternative.